# Why the video's start time output by AVAssetWriter is no zero?

Tags: ios

When i use [PBJVsion](https://github.com/piemonte/PBJVision) to capture a video ,why is the video's start time output by `AVAssetWriter` is not zero?

the video output imformation use some video tools as below:
 major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf55.19.104
  Duration: 00:00:08.12, **start: 0.023220**, bitrate: 1050 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 480x480, 976 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc
    Stream #0.1(und): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 75 kb/s
[17:39:56] scan: decoding previews for title 1

Comment: Can you add the code that you are using so that people can try to establish the problem

Comment: @Adam Richardson Hi,the project is [PBJVsiion](https://github.com/piemonte/PBJVision).